# 3D LUT color correction. Highlights/Shadows

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, signal-processing

I want to transfer my color correction from Lightroom to the cube format. I use hald table 64*64*64 and PIL function, but the result is not the same as after lightroom. If i understand well i loose the information about highlights and shadows, because hald table doesn't have absolute white and black colors and doesn't operate them.
I think I need to apply my color correction to etalon W&B gradient in addition to correction from hald table. But it's just guess and I can't find any information about this method.
Any ideas how can I solve this problem and achieve my goal?

Below 2 results. Bright one after python

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuGOb.jpg)

[Hald table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qgvo.png)

[Python result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQpWl.jpg)

[Lightroom result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qklZE.jpg)

Comment: What other processing is done in your Lightroom processing of the image (blur, sharpen, masking). Not all processing is captured by a 3D lut? What do you mean that a HALD table does not include white or black?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, only color correction, curves, some of light settings etc

Comment: You can try using ImageMagick to apply your HALD image using -hald-clut. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#hald-clut. Or do the same using Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick.

Comment: In Lightroom i use Highlights and Shadows parameters to lighten or darken very dark or bright zones, but result after Hald table is different from result after Lightroom.

Comment: I use this hald table https://3dlutcreator.ru/materials/Hald/HALD_64.png

Comment: If you post your image, I can use ImageMagick to apply it for you and then you can see if that is any better. I think Lightroom Highlights and shadows uses masks to apply filters in different parts of the image. So that would not be captured by the HALD LUT. Anything that is local to certain regions of the image will not be captured. It only captures global color, brightness, contrast like adjustments.

Comment: which size of hald table do you need? I added all images in main question. hald table - 64

Comment: See my comment above yours where I indicate that using Lightroom Shadows and Highlights most likely cannot be reproduced with a 3D LUT since it is specially varying in the image. 3D LUTs only include color and brightness/contrast changes that are globally the same across the whole image.

Comment: i think the same, that's what i'm asking about - How to transfer highlights and shadows?)

Comment: You cannot do that with a 3D LUT. You would have to have the same algorithm in any other tool and Adobe keeps all that very private. I have an ImageMagick script with the same name, but it does not do as good a job as Adobe. But you can find it at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick

Comment: I understand. I think i need to separate this between 2 process. Make color correction with Hald table (without highlights and shadows) and something like tonemap, but use W&B gradient like etalon, where gradient with highlights and shadows correction will be analyze (like hald table analyze the changes in color) and apply this changes to the image